# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Hey guys I have am trying to pass form field values as an array through AJAX to a PHP file that then writes the data to a mysql database.

I have my standard form with a set of field entries:

```
<input type="text" name="rName[]">
<input type="text" name="rDateS[]">
<input type="text" name="rDateF[]">
<input type="text" name="rCost[]">
```

I then push these values on click to my php file

```
$("#addRates_Submit").click(function() { 

    var rName = $('#rName').val();
    var rDateS = $('#rDateS').val();
    var rDateF = $('#rDateF').val();
    var rCost = $('#rCost').val();

        var proceedc = true;

if (proceedc)
{
 //Ajax post data to server
        $.ajax({
               url: "myphpfile",
               type:"POST",
          data: {
                            "rName":rName,"rDateS":rDateS,"rDateF":rDateF,"rCost":rCost},

                dataType: "text",
                success:function(data) {

                // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#resultDiv').html('<center><p style="color:#ffffff;">Rates Added.</p></center>');

                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    $('#resultDiv').html('A problem has occurred.' + errorThrown.responseText);
                    return false;
                }  


}); // end ajax


} // end process

}); // end rates submit click
```

PHP FILE:

```
$rName      = filter_var($_POST["rName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$rDateS      = filter_var($_POST["rDateS"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$rDateF      = filter_var($_POST["rDateF"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$rCost      = filter_var($_POST["rCost"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


foreach($rName as $key => $n ) {

$oaQuery="INSERT INTO property_rates (pID,rName,rDateS,rDateF,rCost) VALUES     ('$pInsertID','$n','$rDateS[$key]','$rDateF[$key]','$rCost[$key]')";
$oaResult=mysql_query($oaQuery);

}
```

From the console log I get the following error:

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 44.  I have tried adding is_array($rName) and that takes the error away but the array doesnt post anything to the db. Is it possible to submit form field arrays through ajax and then have php know what it is or do I need to have the array occur on the jquery side and then pass that jquery array data to a php array.

If I do these inserts as single queries and not in an array it works fine.  But its like the array is never truly being built.  (Side Note:  My form, dynamically adds fields when the user desires each time it adds a field set it labels it rName[], rDateS[],rDateF[],, and rCost[] accordingly.

Comment: Selectors like `$('#rName')` shouldn't work with your input elements. Should be `$("input[name='#rName[]']")`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some problems in your code.

First, if you use $('#rName') you only could have 1 input because the id must be uniq.
Second, if you use $('.rName') you could have a lot of inputs with the same class, but the code

```
var rName = $('#rName').val();
```

only return the value for the first input field.
And finaly, you only get the value as a text and PHP only will recive one variable, not an array.

The solution should be pass through all the input fields and create a string like that:

```
var rname = '';
$(".rName").each(function() {
        rname = rname = '&rname[]='+$(this).val();
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you! Im am implementing this as well as the above comments and ill let you all know.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Curious when I implement this, how does it affect my AJAX data call.

Comment: var rname = '';
   $(".rName").each(function() {
           rname = rname = '&rname[]='+$(this).val();
             });
  var rdates = '';
   $(".rDateS").each(function() {
           rdates = rdates = '&rdates[]='+$(this).val();
             });
  var rdatef = '';
   $(".rDateF").each(function() {
           rdatef = rdatef = '&rdatef[]='+$(this).val();
             });
  var rdatef = '';
   $(".rCost").each(function() {
           rcostf = rcost = '&rcost[]='+$(this).val();
             });

Comment: CURRENT: data: {"rName":rName,"rDateS":rDateS,"rDateF":rDateF,"rCost":rCost},
dataType: "text",

Comment: Should I change this to: data:{"rName":rname,"rDateS":rdates, etc ...}?

Answer (score 0):

This errors means :

- your variable is not an array
- Or it IS an array but it is empty

Do this :

```
if (is_array($rName) && $rName) {
    foreach ($rName as $key => $n) {
       $oaQuery = "INSERT INTO property_rates (pID,rName,rDateS,rDateF,rCost) 
       VALUES('$pInsertID','$n','$rDateS[$key]','$rDateF[$key]','$rCost[$key]')";
        $oaResult = mysql_query($oaQuery);
    }
}
```

And consider that your jQuery selector is wrong, this is because your variable (rName) is **empty**, the correct selector for `<input name='rName'>` is :

```
jQuery('input[name="rName"]');
```

Comment: Thank you! Ill implement this and see where it gets me )